# Is spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client with Spring Boot 3 support already available?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a Spring Boot 2 application with a dependency on `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client:2.11.2`.

I want to upgrade my application to Spring Boot 3, but I receive the following error when launching a task:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode()'
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:881)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:498)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.TaskTemplate.launch(TaskTemplate.java:205)
```

If I understand correctly, this error is due to the fact that `spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client:2.11.2` relies on Spring 5, and my application now uses Spring 6.

I didn't find any newer version than `spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client:2.11.2` that would provide Spring Boot 3 support.
I saw on GitHub that there is a `main-3` branch with Spring Boot 3 upgrade, but I didn't find any Maven artifact for that version neither.

**Question:** is there already a `spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client` with Spring Boot 3 compatibility? If not, what is a reasonable timing I can expect this to be available?

Comment: The process of converting Spring Cloud Data Flow to run on Boot 3 is in progress at the moment.
Do not try to use SCDF 2.x libraries with Boot 3, there are many incompatibilities.